# Does anyone know how can i check if href is equal to current page link in smarty?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, smarty

Does anyone know how can i check if href is equal to current page link in smarty? I want to add a class "active" to a link from a menu.
My code goes something like this

```
<div id="navigation-menu">
        <a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=how_it_works">How it Works</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=prices">Prices</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get the `$_GET['page']` variable using `{$smarty.get.page}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you can do something like:

```
<div id="navigation-menu">
    <a href="index.php"{if $smarty.get.page eq ''} class="active"{/if}>Home</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=how_it_works"{if $smarty.get.page eq 'how_it_works'} class="active"{/if}>How it Works</a>
    <a href="index.php?page=prices"{if $smarty.get.page eq 'prices'} class="active"{/if}>Prices</a>
</div>
```

But not sure, don't know smarty.

Comment: but unfortunately there is little to see :)